# Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: No non-static method "Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList(I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;"

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Check my log

```
Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList(I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;"
01-11 12:48:49.249 I/MonoDroid( 9688):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <fcbf47a04b2e4d90beafbae627e1fca4>:0 
01-11 12:48:49.249 I/MonoDroid( 9688):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.GetMethodID (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, System.String name, System.String signature) [0x0005b] in <3cb12bce834a498199b2be6cd3e00922>:0 
01-11 12:48:49.249 I/MonoDroid( 9688):   at Java.Interop.JniType.GetInstanceMethod (System.String name, System.String signature) [0x0000c] in <3cb12bce834a498199b2be6cd3e00922>:0 
01-11 12:48:49.249 I/MonoDroid( 9688):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.GetMethodInfo (System.String encodedMember) [0x00031] in <3cb12bce834a498199b2be6cd3e00922>:0 
01-11 12:48:49.249 I/MonoDroid( 9688):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00006] in <3cb12bce834a498199b2be6cd3e00922>:0 
01-11 12:48:49.249 I/MonoDroid( 9688):   at Android.Content.Context.GetColorStateList (System.Int32 id) [0x00022] in <551e90b840814b76a3d15b7bbaa8a77c>:0 
01-11 12:48:49.249 I/MonoDroid( 9688):   at Movo.MapActivity+<OnCreate>d__37.MoveNext () [0x000a6] in C:\Users\MapActivity.cs:85 An unhandled exception occured.
```

Answer (score 6):

The **Context**-based `GetColorStateList` was added in API Level 23, so if you try to execute that method on older Android versions it will fail.

Now, in the `com.android.support:support-compat` (version 24.1+) (via Xamarin Nuget Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat), there is a **ContextCompat**-based `GetColorStateList`  that can be used on older (and newer) API levels

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What can I change in my VS project to make it work on API Level 21? This is a MAUI Blazor app fresh from template.